# Which copper adapter should I use for tub spout and what is the difference?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pipe, bathtub, copper

I'm going to sweat a 1/2" piece of copper with a Male Adapter Fitting to thread into the drop-ear for my tub spout.

I purchased this: [1/2 in. Copper Pressure Cup x MIP Male Adapter Fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-Copper-Pressure-Cup-x-MIP-Male-Adapter-Fitting-C604HD12/204620255)

Later online I found this: [1/2 in. Copper FTG x MIP Fitting Adapter Fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-Copper-FTG-x-MIP-Fitting-Adapter-Fitting-C6042HD12/204620308?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-204620260-_-204620308-_-N)

Both seem to appear to do the same thing, yet the latter is 4 times the price of the other with what appears to be just a little more copper.

What's the difference between the 2? Is one better for my application?

Answer (score 2):

The cup fitting slides onto the end of a pipe. The FTG fitting is the same size as pipe and fits directly into some other fitting: an elbow, a coupling, a tee, etc. It probably costs more only because they're infrequently used. The cup fitting is the right one for your application.